# Is there a way to find current environment in a Ruby application similar to rails.env?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I need to implement a feature that sets some Env vars conditionally based on current environment(dev,test,prod). I know in rails this can be accomplished with rails.env. Is there a similar method for Ruby?

Comment: Why do you want to set env vars from ruby code? Are these going to be used by some other program? Or are you then using them in another part of the ruby program? If you are doing the later, why don't you set ruby variables rather than env vars?

Comment: Different environments hit different endpoints and those endpoints are held in environment variables. Not my decision, just my problem

Comment: That sounds pretty standard. My typical solution to this kind of thing is to set the environment variables in my deployment pipeline, not in the ruby code.

Comment: I edited my question to include some more details. TLDR: environment variables should be read, but not set, from the ruby app. Some other mechanism should set them to the values specific to the environment.

Comment: _"find current environment"_ and _"set some env vars"_ are more or less opposite tasks. In Rails, you _set_ the current environment by assigning a value to the `RAILS_ENV` environment variable. You can then use `rails.env` to _retrieve_ that value which is the result of calling `ENV['RAILS_ENV']`. (slightly simplified, the actual code is a little more involved)

Answer (score 2):

No, vanilla ruby doesn't have a concept of "environment". You will have to build this yourself. One simple way is to use an environment variable and read it.

For example, you can require a `MYAPP_ENVIRONMENT` environment variable. Then you read it with `myapp_environment = ENV['MYAPP_ENVIRONMENT']`. Then you might have hashes or some other data structure to determine values that are specific to that environment:

```
ENDPOINT_A = {
    prod: 'https://prod.my_company.com',
    stage: 'https://stage.my_company.com'
}
```

Similarly for other variables. Note that the endpoint string is a ruby variable, not an environment variable. You should NOT set environment variables from the ruby code that uses them. The whole point of environment variables is that they are set externally to your app and your app takes them as input to configure how it behaves.

If you want to specify the endpoint through an environment variable, you should set it in the operating system where your ruby app runs. You can do this manually on the machine or through a deployment pipeline or script.